# preg_match unknown modifier '.' in wordpress

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to do something simple...I thought?

Have the following...

```
$current = '/zeta/2010/03/';

preg_match('/zeta/.{4}/(.{2})/$',$current,$monthnum);
```

Simply am trying to make `$monthnum = 03`

Keep either getting an unknown modifier error or, when I add the delimiters `'#/zeta/.{4}/(.{2})/$#` it returns with simply `#Array`...

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you already know how to solve the modifier error, why don't you have a look at the array?

Answer (score 3):

PCREs have to be enclosed in delimiters.

You have to either escape the inner `\` or use another delimiter:

```
~/zeta/.{4}/(.{2})/$~'
```

Otherwise, PHP thinks the expression is `/zeta/` only and `.` is not a [valid modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

[**`preg_match`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) does not return an array. You can inspect the contents of `$monthnum` with `var_dump` and access the information you want.

You could have solved your problem by simply reading the documentation:

> If *`matches`* is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. *`$matches[0]`* will contain the text that matched the full pattern, *`$matches[1]`* will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

and

> **preg_match()** returns the number of times *pattern* matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because **preg_match()** will stop searching after the first match.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

As you can read, the function itself returns true or false if it matches something. When the function returns true, $monthnum will be created as an array, where $monthnum[0] is the complete match, and any following parts you specified to fetch in your regexp will be loaded after that. In your case, the part:

`([0-9]{2})`

will be loaded into $monthnum[1]